# Is there a big difference between coding for Mobile apps vs Web apps

Tags: android, web-applications, mobile-application

I am on the cusp of recieving a new project that involves creating a mobile app for android tablets. Is there a large difference in coding for web apps vs mobile apps. And is there any good links I can go to read up on it more? This will be in .Net by the way

Comment: Are you talking about *web applications* targeted for mobile devices or actual native applications for mobile devices?

Comment: I am presumming native applications installed on the device itself?

Comment: are you using [Mono for Android](http://android.xamarin.com/) then? Because I know of no other working solution for using .NET on Android.

Comment: That is the thing I am not sure what I should use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, obviously both involve coding, so they are quite similar at this level.

But the restrictions that apply to you are quite different.

- on a sever application, the size of the libraries you use don't usually make a difference, while the installation size of a mobile app is a *definite* issue
- memory and processing power are *usually* are less of an issue on the server, as compared to a mobile device
- each mobile platform usually has it's own UI framework with quite unique concepts (at least each *interesting* platform does it its own way)
- the APIs are quite different (it's rare to have the *same* API for server applications and mobile applications)

So yes, there is quite a difference between writing a web-application and writing a native smartphone application.

Comment: ok thank you. This application will be an installed app on the android tablet itself, so I guess this is what is called a native mobile device application correct. I am a quick learner so i want to be able to do this without much downtime. I downloaded MonoDevelop, will this work for creating these native device applications? I know that it will be one specific model that the company uses that these applications will e deployed on.

Comment: @mattgcon: Note that Mono for Android (which I *think* is the new name for MonoDroid) is a commercial application and I don't know of any free way to write .NET code to run on Android. I'd suggest you try to write a "normal" Java android application: You'll have to learn a lot of new APIs anyway and Java really isn't that different from C#.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally coding is coding, but as with anything you are going to be using a different language with android and a different architecture for setting things up. I would suggest reading through the developer documents at developer.android.com and depending on how well you know java maybe do some studying on the basics of java development. www.thenewboston.com helped me a ton when I was first starting to program.